# Why didn't Xavier go back in time?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

In *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Kitty Pryde can send people's minds back in time to their younger selves. Because of the strain this puts on the mind, she can only send most people back a few days at most. When she needs to send someone back 50 years, that limits her options to Professor Xavier and Wolverine, whose powers can protect them from any negative effects.

Xavier says that he can't help, because he didn't have his powers in 1973, so Wolverine is sent.

However, we later learn that the medication he was taking to enable him to use his legs suppressed his mutant abilities. When he stops taking it his powers return fairly quickly, to the point that he is even able to communicate with his future self through Wolverine's mind.

So, couldn't old Xavier have gone back in time, stopped taking the medication, and then fixed things? Besides [giving Wolverine more screentime](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WolverinePublicity), is there a reason for this?

Comment: As I recall it, Xavier was never an option because his mind wouldn't be able to withstand the damage done during a long trip back. Young-Xavier's lack of powers was an issue in regards to being unable to stop the assassination.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are confused about Xavier's powers. They never said in the movie that Xavier's powers would protect him during the trip. He actually wouldn't survive the trip, his mind wouldn't take it:

> **Pryde:** I can send someone back a couple of weeks...maybe a month but you're talking about going back decades. **You have the most powerful brain in the world Professor, but the mind can only stretch so far before it snaps. It would rip you apart.** I'm sorry, no one could survive that trip.

Wolverine is the only person who could heal like that, therefore he is the only person who can make the trip.

The part where Xavier says he can't help due to his lack of powers is when they talk about Wolverine trying to get Xavier to work with him:

> **Wolverine:** So I wake up in my younger body, God knows where, and then what?
>
> **Xavier:** You'll need to go to my house and find me. Convince me of all this.
>
> **Wolverine:** Won't you be able to read my mind?
>
> **Xavier:** I didn't have my powers in 1973. Logan, you're going to have to do for me what I once did for you: lead me, guide me. I was a very different man then. You'll have to be patient with me.